# How to generate multiple database from a single source without using UNION?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to generate some data outputs using different date filter from a same source. I could do this by using UNION, but it takes a lot of time. Is there anyway to do this without using UNION?

The source table would be like this

source_keyword_table:

```
| keyword | start_date | end_date   |
+---------+------------+------------+
| abc     | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-07 |
+---------+------------+------------+
| cde     | 2020-02-03 | 2020-02-07 |
+---------+------------+------------+
| fgh     | 2020-03-01 | 2020-03-02 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

In details, I would like to generate these data:
1. Keyword performance from abc between 2020-01-01 AND 2020-01-07
2. Keyword performance from def between 2020-02-03 AND 2020-02-07
3. Keyword performance from ghi between 2020-03-01 AND 2020-03-02

**I could use below query:**

```
SELECT b.date, keyword, COUNT(DISTINCT search_id) total_search
FROM source_keyword_table a
JOIN total_search_table b USING (keyword)
WHERE b.date BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM source_keyword_table) AND (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM source_keyword_table)
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

*That query would return some output from some date that is not needed*

**The second alternative would be:**

```
SELECT b.date, keyword, COUNT(DISTINCT search_id) total_search
FROM source_keyword_table a
JOIN total_search_table b USING (keyword)
WHERE b.date BETWEEN (SELECT start_date FROM source_keyword_table WHERE keyword = 'abc') AND (SELECT end_date FROM source_keyword_table WHERE keyword = 'abc')
GROUP BY 1, 2

UNION ALL

SELECT b.date, keyword, COUNT(DISTINCT search_id) total_search
FROM source_keyword_table a
JOIN total_search_table b USING (keyword)
WHERE b.date BETWEEN (SELECT start_date FROM source_keyword_table WHERE keyword = 'def') AND (SELECT end_date FROM source_keyword_table WHERE keyword = 'def')
GROUP BY 1, 2

UNION ALL

SELECT b.date, keyword, COUNT(DISTINCT search_id) total_search
FROM source_keyword_table a
JOIN total_search_table b USING (keyword)
WHERE b.date BETWEEN (SELECT start_date FROM source_keyword_table WHERE keyword = 'ghi') AND (SELECT end_date FROM source_keyword_table WHERE keyword = 'ghi')
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

I would like to do the second alternative, but it's a lot work to do when I have hundreds or thousands of data row. Is there any way to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood what you seek for. You want to select **_date, keyword, COUNT(DISTINCT search_id)_** from the result of the `INNER JOIN` of your two tables _source_keyword_table_ and _total_search_table_. However, the condition is that each keyword's date ( from the 2nd table) must be between the start and end date for the same keyword from the first table, if the condition is met the columns are retrieved. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Also, why do you use `max` and `min` in your 1st approach? Do you have repeated keywords in source_keyword_table?

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT b.date, a.keyword, COUNT(DISTINCT search_id) AS total_search  
FROM `project.dataset.total_search_table` b
JOIN `project.dataset.source_keyword_table` a
ON b.keyword = a.keyword
AND b.date BETWEEN a.start_date AND a.end_date
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard as you are on BigQuery.

There are some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations) you need to account for, but as for your example, seems like you have a common compatible schema, so you can just do:

```
SELECT date, keyword, COUNT(DISTINCT search_id) total_search
FROM common_table_name_*
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

The * defines the wildcard. You can also use [suffixes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix).

If your tables don't have a `common_table_name_` that you can refer to, you can call them at the top as CTEs or creating views for them, although this would beat the purpose I believe.